# Do you have to be a paid user to edit your form submission?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm confused about the term 'users'.

Does it mean 'administrator' or 'person who submits a form'?

We want around 250 local attractions to be able to fill in a form and come back and edit it periodically.

Does this mean we have to pay for 250 users?

Answer (score 1):

On the [pricing page](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing), 'users' refers to the administrators and other individuals who create and share forms, while 'entries' refers to the total number of form submissions. The Individual plan, for example, allows up to 500 entries per month.

Comment: Excellent. So can you confirm that anyone who submits a form will then be able to revisit it and amend their submission at a later date, providing that the total number of submissions / changes does not exceed our paid plan?

Comment: Correct; this is possible through the entry sharing feature, which is available to organizations on the Pro, Team, and Enterprise plans. People can still edit their entries when your form exceeds the submission limit, but you will be unable to view new entries until you upgrade your plan.